# FCM OnTokenRefresh() method is not called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get a device token from FCM.
This code is working in the demo project, but when I try to use it in my project, the OnTokenRefresh method is not called. I did all setup perfectily but i don't know why method is not called.

Thank you.

**FirebaseInstanceIDService.cs**

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
[System.Obsolete]
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    // [START refresh_token]
    [System.Obsolete]
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"######Token######  :  {refreshedToken}");
       
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["Fcmtocken"] = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token ?? "";
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
   
    base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    NotificationCenter.CreateNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannelRequest());
    Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
    
    FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
    
    LoadApplication(new App());
    NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(Intent);           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is obsolete.

For startup scenarios you should implement a `Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener` somewhere and register that listener like so:

```cs
FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(context);
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken().AddOnSuccessListener(<your listener instance here>);
```

Then change FirebaseInstanceIdService to FirebaseMessagingService instead:

```cs
[Service(Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public sealed class MyMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        // you got a notification
    }

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        // you got a new token
    }
}
```